# GCP Alerting Policy to Alert on KMS Key Deletion Using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am trying to alert on KMS Key deletions using terraform.
I have a log based metric, a policy and a notification channel to PagerDuty.
This all works, however, following the alert triggering it soon clears and there seems to be nothing I can do to stop this.
Here is my code:

```
resource "google_logging_metric" "logging_metric" {
    name        = "kms-key-pending-deletion"
    description = "Logging metric used to alert on scheduled deletions of KMS keys"
    filter      = "resource.type=cloudkms_cryptokeyversion AND protoPayload.methodName=DestroyCryptoKeyVersion"
    metric_descriptor {
        metric_kind  = "DELTA"
        value_type   = "INT64"
        unit         = "1"
        display_name = "kms-key-pending-deletion-metric-descriptor"
    }
}

resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "pagerduty_alerts" {
    display_name = "pagerduty-notification-channel"
    type         = "pagerduty"
    sensitive_labels {
        service_key = var.token
    }
}

resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "kms_key_deletion_alert_policy" {
    display_name          = "kms-key-deletion-alert-policy"
    combiner              = "OR"
    notification_channels = [google_monitoring_notification_channel.pagerduty_alerts.name]
    conditions {
        display_name = "kms-key-deletion-alert-policy-conditions"
        condition_threshold {
            comparison      = "COMPARISON_GT"
            duration        = "300s"
            filter          = "metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/kms-key-pending-deletion\" AND resource.type=\"global\""
            threshold_value = "0"
        }
    }
    documentation {
        content = "Runbook: https://blah"
    }
}
```

In the GCP GUI I can disable the option "Notify on incident closure" in the policy and it stops the alert from clearing.
However I cannot set this via terraform.
I have tried setting alert_strategy.auto_close to null and 0s but this did not work:

```
alert_strategy {
    auto_close = "0s"
    # auto_close = null
}
```

How do I keep the alert active and stop it from clearing when building the policy in terraform?
Am I using the correct resource type? - Should I be using cloudkms.cryptoKey.state that are in "DESTROY_SCHEDULED" state somehow?

Answer (score 0):

For others wanting to find the answer to this:

The need to keep an alert open and not allow it to automatically close is missing in the API.
The issue is tracked here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/151052441?pli=1